# Access remote EJB from separate Wildfly Swarm

Tags: java, wildfly, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10, wildfly-swarm

My goal:

To access `@Remote` EJB from separate Wildfly Swarm server

Current code:
Bean on wildfly swarm:

```
@Startup @Singleton
public class Bean1 {
    @Inject private LoginFacade loginFacade;

    @PostConstruct void setup() {
        System.out.println(loginFacade.getCurrentUserWithoutSession());
    }
}
```

Config bean on swarm:

```
@Startup @Singleton
public class Config {
    @Produces
    public Context context() throws NamingException {
        final Hashtable<String, Object> props = new Hashtable<>();
        props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        return new InitialContext(props);
    }

    @Produces
    public LoginFacade loginFacadeBean(Context context) throws NamingException {
        return (LoginFacade) context.lookup("ejb:or/project//LoginFacadeBean!f.q.d.n.LoginFacade");
    }
}
```

Swarm config:

```
---
swarm:
  http:
    port: 8081
  logging: DEBUG
  remoting:
    remote-outbound-connections:
      remote-ejb-connection:
        security-realm: ejb-security-realm
        username: qazwsxmko
        outbound-socket-binding-ref: remote-ejb
        properties:
          SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT:
            value: "false"
          SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS:
            value: "false"
          SSL_ENABLED:
            value: "false"
  management:
    security-realms:
      ejb-security-realm:
        secret-server-identity:
          value: "cWF6d3N4bWtvMQ=="
    http:
      port: 9991
  network:
    socket-binding-groups:
      standard-sockets:
        outbound-socket-bindings:
          remote-ejb:
            remote-host: localhost
            remote-port: 8080
```

Meaningful parts of standalone-full.xml from remote wildfly:

```
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        <!---->
        <http-connector name="mobile-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
```

On launching application I'm getting following error:

```
2018-09-20 20:32:23,953 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."demo.war".component.Bean1.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."demo.war".component.Bean1.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:124)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:138)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYSEC0027: Invalid User
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:49)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
        at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:328)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:67)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:201)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.processMessage(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:263)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.processMessage(VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.java:213)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versiontwo.VersionTwoProtocolChannelReceiver.processMessage(VersionTwoProtocolChannelReceiver.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.handleMessage(VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.java:159)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel$5.run(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:456)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor$1.run(EndpointImpl.java:731)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Obviously I've checked login/password many times, created new users and so on.

Just before showing error application writes in logs several messages, containing following string

> Received MODULE_AVAILABLE(8) message for module "module name here"

Which makes me thing that one server is able to connect to another

My server is wildfly 10.1, version of wildfly swarm is 2.2.0